# X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode block not working against reflected XSS

Tags: xss

****X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode block not working against reflected XSS****

GET /ApplicationName/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?ReportSession=3goqe355i5khffrdfeofm2en&ControlID=1b5a5c1c7e314d1dabbb0797bf093da3&Culture=1033&UICulture=1033&ReportStack=1&OpType=SessionKeepAlive&TimerMethod=KeepAliveMethodcntPlcHolder_ReportViewer1TouchSession038999%3balert(1)%2f%2f705&CacheSeed=Fri%20Apr%2013%202018%2015%3A41%3A24%20GMT%2B0530%20(India%20Standard%20Time) HTTP/1.1

Doing Attack from above response when we show report in Microsoft Report Viewer.

Is any solution for this?

Comment: Report to MS or check if is already reported? BTW I see no XSS in that line. Could it be a false positive?

Comment: wonder it it is not best suited for other site, security related ones...

Comment: @ bradbury9 Please check XSS after word TouchSession

Comment: As long as in web.config file probably says that it is MS dll the one that handles the requests for the axd, I only think of IIS XSS prevention. A quick search point me to  https://serverfault.com/questions/347478/does-iis7-have-in-built-or-available-extensions-for-responding-to-scan-attempt

Comment: @ bradbury Thank You very much  i got idea about the sql injection. but requestFiltering can apply on given problem?

Comment: If you dont control the assembly that resolves the request of the resource, the only way I think of preventing it is IIS filtering.

Comment: @ bradbury Thank you again. i'll try this solutions.If you know more about preventing XSS then please let me know.

Comment: I would suggest you going to other sites like https://security.stackexchange.com/ where more specialized ppl could help better.

Comment: Okay Thank you ..